# How to get a specific grade data using Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

**What I want**:

1. To get the `grade` of what the user answered in the database if exists and get the grade of that answer.

**What I have**:

1. I have `3` tables, `short_answer`, `sa_sa_answer`, `short_answer_answer`.
2. Now, `short_answer` table has question, and each question has many answer located in the `short_answer_answer` table and the grade is also included there, the question can have **1 or more** answer.

**What code I have:**

*Controller*

```
foreach($sa_question_id as $key => $value){
   $sa = ShortAnswer::with('answers')->find($sa_question_id[$key]);
   $possible_answers = [];

   foreach($sa->answers as $possible_answer){
      $possible_answers[] .= strtolower($possible_answer->answer);
   }

   if(in_array(strtolower($sa_answer[$key]), $possible_answers)){
      $grade = ShortAnswerAnswer::where('answer', $sa_answer[$key])->get();
      echo "plus +1. Grade is: " . $grade->grade . "<br>";
   }
}
```

**The problem is:**

Im just getting the answer where the answer is equal to the user's answer. But what if I have **TWO** same answer and different `grade` and obviously different question. It can select the wrong one.

**Note:** *I'm using Laravel5.1*

**Update:** *Table Structure*

`short_answer` 
 - `name` 
 - `question`

`sa_sa_answer`
 - `short_answer_id`
 - `short_answer_answer_id`

`short_answer_answer`
 - `answer`
 - `grade`

**[Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46480439/how-to-continue-a-quiz-with-a-collection-of-data-entered-by-the-user-in-laravel5)**

I've already solved this issue, however no one got the bounty, but If you could answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46480439/how-to-continue-a-quiz-with-a-collection-of-data-entered-by-the-user-in-laravel5), I can give you the bounty plus **2** check mark and up vote, I just really need more help with this. It is also connected with this question. The bounty will be gone in 3 days from now.

Comment: Indeed. I updated it. Please have a look at it now

Answer (score 3):

We can solve this problem using a single query:

```
$questions = ShortAnswer::with('answers')
    ->whereIn('id', $sa_question_id)
    ->whereHas('answers', function ($query) use ($sa_answer) {
        $placeholders = join(",", array_pad([], count($sa_answer), "?"));
        $query->whereRaw("LOWER(answer) IN $placeholders", $sa_answer);
    })
    ->get(); 

foreach ($questions as $question) {
    foreach ($question->answers as $answer) {
        echo 'plus +1. Grade is: ' + $answer->grade}."; 
    }
}
```

This optimizes out the loop so we only need to query the database once for all the questions and answers. It also solves the problem in the question because the query maintains the relationships between question and answer, so we won't inadvertently select the wrong answers for the questions.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code:

```
$grade = ShortAnswerAnswer::where('answer', $sa_answer[$key])->get();
```

You are getting all answers from `ShortAnswerAnswer` that equals to `$sa_answer[$key]`, there is no condition to point out if the answer you get from the proper question that you expected.

So, to solve your problem, you need to point out the question as well. Like:

```
$grade = ShortAnswerAnswer::where(['answer' => $sa_answer[$key], 'question_id' => $key])->get();
```

---

P/s:
This part:

```
foreach($sa_question_id as $key => $value){
   $sa = ShortAnswer::with('answers')->find($sa_question_id[$key]);
   ...
}
```

Then, `$sa_question_id[$key]` is exactly `$value`.

Comment: Is this available in laravel5.1? `$grade = ShortAnswerAnswer::where([
    ['answer', $sa_answer[$key]],
    ['question_id', $key],
])->get();`

Comment: I don't have the field `question_id` in `short_answer_answer` table.

Comment: So which field in `short_answer_answer` table to determine the question of the corresponding answer?

Comment: `$grade = ShortAnswerAnswer::where([ ['answer', $sa_answer[$key]], ['question_id', $key], ])->get();` is supported in Laravel 5.3.

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.1

Comment: I have a table `sa_sa_answer` where I can use `belongsToMany` relationship. so maybe we can use that table

Comment: Can you give me the structure of those tables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155221/discussion-between-duc-filan-and-jonjie).