# How to continue a quiz with a collection of data entered by the user in laravel5.1

Tags: loops, laravel-5.1

I'm gonna go straight forward for this. This question is connected with [my passed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355609/how-to-get-a-specific-grade-data-using-laravel-eloquent), I will offer you the bounty within 3 days from now if you solved this problem.

**What I want**

After the user answered a quiz, the user can save it without submitting, so they can edit/continue later. Now, after they saved, how can I loop through the user's answer in the current loop of questions in a quiz? So that the user can edit or continue the quiz.

**What I have**

*database:*

**`quiz_result_of_user`** has `9` fields, `['id', 'quiz_id', 'user_id', 'question_id', 'answer', 'question_type', 'attempt_number', 'marks', 'grades']`

- This table saves all the user's answer so this serves as the history table of the user's quiz.

**`quizattempt_user`** has `3` fields, `['id', 'quiz_id', 'user_id']`

- This table saves all the user's attempt, so I can reference all the answer of the user `where` the `id` `=` `attempt_number` in the **`quiz_result_of_user`** table.

*Controller* - **Update**

```
$quiz = Quiz::with('multiple_choices.answers', 'true_false', 'short_answer', 'descriptions')->findOrFail($id);

$questions = collect($quiz->multiple_choices);
$questions = $questions->merge(collect($quiz->true_false));
$questions = $questions->merge(collect($quiz->short_answer));
$questions = $questions->merge(collect($quiz->descriptions));
$questions = $questions->sortBy('question_number');
```

**Problem**

I can now loop through the questions, and the answers of the user, but I can't figure out how can I put the user's answer because it is also a collection of data. **Note:** every quiz can have different types of question, `multiple choice`, `true or false`, and `short answer/fill in the blank`.

Comment: In user's answer collection apply sorting based on attempt number and get last from the collection. 

Eg: `$answers->sortBy('attempt_number')->last()`

Comment: I answered the previous question, but this question is very difficult to answer without more information and examples. Particularly, how do you fetch the quiz results and the user's answers? What does the data look like in the `quiz_result_of_user` table's `answer` column? How are the model relationships set up? I'd love to help , but the question needs more context relevant to the question.

Comment: Please check my update

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I understand of the table structure, we can create a dictionary of the user's answers keyed by the the question IDs, so we can easily look up the answer for each question. Here's a minimal implementation that we can expand on:

```php
$questions = ... // see question description
$answers = QuizResults::where('quiz_id', $quiz->id)
    ->where('user_id', $userId)
    ->where('attempt_number', $attemptNumber)
    ->get()
    ->keyBy('question_id');

foreach ($questions as $question) 
{ 
    echo $question->question_number + ". " + $question->description; 

    if ($question is MultipleChoice) {
        foreach ($question->answers as $choice) { echo $choice; ... }
    } 

    echo 'Your answer: ' + $answers->get($question->id)->first()->answer; 
}
```

I'm not sure if the page uses Blade to generate the results. For clarity, this is written in plain PHP, but it should be easy to rewrite this for a Blade template.